# Finally EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I have several EditText.

When the User clicks on the first, the keyboard appears, enter the value he and ready.

It's okay, but I wanted when I finished typing the value had an OK button, or complete.

On the keyboard that is shown is only a forward button, which goes straight to the next value of EditText.

I do not want to be next EditText.
I do not know happened to intender.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the soft keyboard to show a Done button instead of the Next button.

In your XML for the EditText, add: `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Alternatively, you can do it via code: `yourEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is that you want to control where the focus of the Activity goes.

Try using an OnFocusChangeListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html and in your onFocusChange method check to see if the view receiving the focus change is your EditText.